# Displaying a list of folders in one directory as items using Base Adapter

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have an issue here. I got an app that adds folder in the app's directory itself using mkdir in a secondary activity.

```
fun createFolder (v: View){
        //Make folder
        val folderName = addFolderField.text.toString()
        val dir1 =  this.getDir("picture", Context.MODE_PRIVATE) //this is to make directory as well
        File(dir1, folderName).mkdir()
        finish()
```

Assuming that I have multiple folders created. How then do I display a the list of folders using Base Adapter in my Main Activity

Answer (score 0):

Create a `activity_list_files.xml`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <ListView android:id="@android:id/list" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And a `ListFileActivity`

```
public class ListFileActivity extends ListActivity {

private String path;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_files);

// Use the current directory as title
path = "/";
if (getIntent().hasExtra("path")) {
  path = getIntent().getStringExtra("path");
}
setTitle(path);

// Read all files sorted into the values-array
List values = new ArrayList();
File dir = new File(path);
if (!dir.canRead()) {
  setTitle(getTitle() + " (inaccessible)");
}
String[] list = dir.list();
if (list != null) {
  for (String file : list) {
    if (!file.startsWith(".")) {
      values.add(file);
    }
  }
}
Collections.sort(values);

// Put the data into the list
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, android.R.id.text1, values);
setListAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
String filename = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
if (path.endsWith(File.separator)) {
  filename = path + filename;
} else {
  filename = path + File.separator + filename;
}
if (new File(filename).isDirectory()) {
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, ListFileActivity.class);
  intent.putExtra("path", filename);
  startActivity(intent);
} else {
  Toast.makeText(this, filename + " is not a directory", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
}
```

Where `path` is the complete directory path where you are creating your folders. The activity displays all files within this path. If we switch the path, we switch to a new activity displaying all files within the given directory.

Also make sure you are adding `uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"` in your manifest.